# CSS3 multiple backgrounds across selectors

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is to set background in two separate CSS classes (using CSS3's multiple backgrounds would be great). I would like to that with as little markup as possible and to be universal.

Example:

**CSS**

```
.button {
    display: block;
}

.green {
    background-color: #87b400;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a4d400,  #739e00);
}

.icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.icon.add {
    background-image: url('../img/icons/add.png');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="button green icon add">add item</a>
<input type="submit" name="example" value="add item" class="button green icon add" />
<button type="submit" class="button green icon add">add item</button>
```

I realize that i can do something like that

```
<a href="#" class="button green"><span class="icon add">add item</span></a>
```

but I think that there is a better way and I wouldn't be able to use it inside `input` element.

I also don't want to do something like this

```
.button.green.icon.add {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a4d400,  #739e00),
                url('../img/icons/add.png');
}
```

because having, let's say, 5 colors and 11 icons it is going to be a horror.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using? Could make a difference as I think multiple background support is still pretty patchy.

Comment: Question is not about browser support, no problem with that :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DaiYoukai is right, CSS3 multiple image backgrounds - can not be used across selectors.

Workaround: you can use CSS3 Content feature - it virtually create additional element.

**CSS**

```
.icon{
    background-image: url('../img/icons/icon.png');
    width:16px;
    height:16px;   
}
.icon.add:after {/* new virtual layer */       
    background-image: url('../img/icons/icon_add.png');
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}
```

Note: Modern browsers correctly supports both CSS3 features, except IE:

- CSS3 multiple backgrounds - from IE9.
- CSS3 Content - from IE8.

Comment: IE can burn to the ground.......and then we will pour gasoline over it....

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't thought of that! It works great with the :before selector as well if the background content happens to overlap your content.

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that CSS3 multiple image backgrounds are only possible in the same declaration.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering

Comment: Hmmm... I think You're right. But what would be the best solution in your opinion? Is it the one I proposed in P.S.?

Comment: @wojtiku Personally, I would just go with using the extra span for the icon css. You would have to make a separate class entirely for the input elements though `background: url('../img/icons/add.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a4d400,  #739e00);`

Comment: Hmmm... when I think about it this is only solution that makes sense. But to make it more universal maybe it's better to wrap `a`/`input`/`button` with a `div` so we get something like this `<div class="button green"><a href="#" class="icon add">add item</a></div>` - this way we can style all 3 versions properly.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option:

```js
$(".green, .icon.add").each(function () {
  var backgrounds = [];
  if ($(this).hasClass("green"))
    backgrounds.push("linear-gradient(#a4d400,  #739e00)");
  if ($(this).hasClass("icon") && $(this).hasClass("add"))
    backgrounds.push("url('../img/icons/add.png')");
  $(this).css("background", backgrounds.join(", "));
});
```

The solution with `:after` can have some unwanted side effects in some situations, and you can only have one of it. With this you can have an unlimited amount of backgrounds.